# Unable to install OEM driver for android on windows 8.1

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-8.1, usb-debugging

I am unable to install the OEM drivers for android debugging on windows 8.1 64 bit OS. I have done following steps so far.

1. Downloaded the android usb drivers from SDK manager. Placed under D drive Android SDK directory. Enabled the USB debugging on my phone via developer options.

Path of drivers on my computer:

D:\Program Files\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

2. I also made changes as suggested at few places to enable the installation of unsigned drivers on windows 8.1 (chosen step 7 in advance system settings)
3. My phone which runs 4.2.2 android version is detected on my system (connected as media device). I also tried as PTP camera but no luck.

Finally the problem. When I go to device manager and do an update driver, i select the option to look for driver on my computer. I gave the path under D drive as above. When I click on next windows says "can not find the driver".
Please help me , I am unable to understand what could be the problem

Thanks

[image: Driver selection]!

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZniTn.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just for the sake of beginners like me who came across this issue. I was able to resolve this by downloading USB drivers from your supported device website. For me I had MotoG so i went to motorola website and downloaded the motorola device manager which installed the relevant usb drivers. Immediately everything went fine, and i was able to run app on my device using android studio.

Answer (score 1):

In windows 8.1, follow the below given steps to install oem drivers for your device:

1. Right click on my computer.
2. Choose properties.
3. Select device manager.
4. In device manager, look for your device name in list of unidentified devices.
5. Select "Update Driver Software"
6. Choose "Browse My Computer for Driver Software"
7. Choose "Let me pick from a list of devices"
8. Select all devices
9. Select have cd option
10. Browse to the google usb driver folder and select winusb.inf
11. Click next until the drivers are installed.

Comment: When i navigate to the folder, it does not let me select any file. I could select only the folders. Moreover, i do not see winusb.inf file there in my usb_driver folder. Updated question with the snapshot of usb_driver folder

Comment: "android_winusb" is the .inf file. It is important is Number 9, in german it should say "Datenträger..."  there you can choose a .ini file and not a whole directory!

Comment: Number 9 ? sorry I could not understand what did you mean ? i mean where i can find an option to choose an inf file not a whole directory